# How to interpret mean_test_score and std_test_score?

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to tune hyperparams of the KerasRegressor model using GridSearchCV that has score = "r2" .
The code

```
    means = gs.cv_results_['mean_test_score']
    stds = gs.cv_results_['std_test_score']
    params = gs.cv_results_['params']
    for mean, stdev, param in zip(means, stds, params):
        print("Summary: %f (%f) with: %r" % (mean, stdev, param))
```

outputs the results below. I'm concerned that r2 is so  different. Especially negatives that mean that model is performing poorly.
Does it mean that there is an underlying problem ?

```
Summary: -0.005585 (0.234004) with: {'batch_size': 5,}
Summary: 0.849829 (0.023618) with: {'batch_size': 5, batch_size': 10, 'epochs': 100}
Summary: -0.210410 (0.131035) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 10}
Summary: 0.294107 (0.261391) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 50}
Summary: 0.857905 (0.006955) with: {'batch_size': 20, 'epochs': 100}
Summary: -0.381018 (0.118675) with: {'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 10}
Summary: -0.053815 (0.321491) with: {'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 50}
Summary: 0.582999 (0.195620) with: {'batch_size': 40, 'epochs': 100}
Summary: -0.413765 (0.114058) with: {'batch_size': 60, 'epochs': 10}
Summary: -0.018707 (0.090325) with: {'batch_size': 60, 'epochs': 50}
Summary: 0.205208 (0.157954) with: {'batch_size': 60, 'epochs': 100}
Summary: -0.423384 (0.112643) with: {'batch_size': 80, 'epochs': 10}
Summary: -0.077780 (0.101668) with: {'batch_size': 80, 'epochs': 50}
Summary: -0.000941 (0.345382) with: {'batch_size': 80, 'epochs': 100}
Summary: -0.427151 (0.112105) with: {'batch_size': 100, 'epochs': 10}
Summary: -0.177046 (0.125664) with: {'batch_size': 100, 'epochs': 50}
```

The  Training dataset shape is (9073, 5), test: (477, 5)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

R2 indicates the proportion of data points which lie within the line created by the regression equation. A higher value of R2 is desirable as it indicates better results.

You need to standardize the minimum to 0 and the maximum to one, since r2 is a proportion of the line. A negative % is not possible.

since the minimum is zero you cant have it in the denominator, so you have to set it like this

so use `1 - [0/r1]`

there is a python module for fixing this error

```py
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. I'm not sure I've understood your reply. Could you please explain what standardisation you mean and why/how to use r2_score if it's already used in GridSearchCV?  As far as I know r2 can be negative. Just means that the model performs worse than the horizontal line (mean), i.e basically model can't make sense of the data. What I can't understand is why my r2 values are all over the place.